# java: If I assign a variable the same value as just before, does it change the memory or does JIT recognize this?

Tags: java, jvm, jit

For example:

```
class Main {
   public boolean hasBeenUpdated = false;

   public void updateMain(){
     this.hasBeenUpdated = true;
     /*
     alternative:
     if(!hasBeenUpdated){
       this.hasBeenUpdated = true;
     }
     */
   }

   public void persistUpdate(){
     this.hasBeenUpdated = false;
   }
}

public Main instance = new Main()
instance.updateMain()
instance.updateMain()
instance.updateMain()
```

Does instance.hasBeenUpdated get updated 3 times in memory?

The reason I ask this is because I hoped to use a boolean("hasBeenUpdated") as a flag, and this could theoretically be "changed" many, many times, before I call "instance.persistUpdate()".

Does the JVM's JIT see this and perform an optimization?

Comment: Just curiosity honestly. Just wanted to know am I actually changeing the memory each time with this operation (I know it is very small optimization), or is there optimization with JIT

Comment: From a hardware perspective you are likely changing cache or data in a write buffer, or even just a renamed register. So "actually changing memory" becomes quite a nebulous concept.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. 1) What does this have to do [tag:scala]? The code you showed is Java code, not Scala code. Scala and Java are two completely different programming languages. 2) Are you asking about [tag:java] or about [tag:jvm]? Those are two completely different things. 3) Which version of which implementation with which configuration, command line flags, etc. are you talking about? Neither the Scala Language Specification, nor the Java Language Specification, nor the JVM Specification (and yes, those are three independent things) specifies how code is supposed to be compiled.

Comment: … In fact, neither of the three even says that code must be compiled *at all* or that code must be optimized at all. 4) The code you showed doesn't even *typecheck*. It doesn't make sense to speculate about the runtime behavior of code that *cannot possibly run* because it is not well-typed.

Answer (score 4):

JIT will collapse redundant statements only when it can PROVE that removing the code will not change the behavior.  For example, if you did this:

```
int i;
i = 1;
i = 1;
i = 1;
```

The first two assignments are provably redundant, and the JIT *could* eliminate them.  If instead it's

```
int i;
i = someMethodReturningInt();
i = someMethodReturningInt();
i = someMethodReturningInt();
```

the JIT has no way of knowing what `someMethodReturnintInt()` does, including whether it has any side effects, so it must invoke the method 3 times.  Whether or not it actually stores any but the final value is immaterial, as the code would behave the same either way.  (Declaring `volatile int i;` instead would force it to store each value)

Of course if you're doing other things in between the method invocations the it will be forced to perform the assignment.

The whole topic is part of the more general "happens-before" and "happens-after" concepts documented in the language and JVM specifications.

Optimization is NEVER supposed to change the behavior of a program, except possibly to reduce its runtime.  There have been instances where bugs in the optimizer inadvertently *did* introduce errors, but these have been few and far between.  In general you don't need to worry about whether optimization will break your code.

Comment: It's at least theoretically possible, especially if `Main`, `updateMain` and every method called in between are `final`, that after inlining, the JIT could eliminate the duplicate assignments.  `javac`/`scalac` (since scala is a tag for this question) could conceivably in that situation do global optimizations themselves to not even emit the bytecode.

Comment: It might  be possible to construct such a situation, but it still shouldn't change the behavior of the code.  If it does change the behavior then it's a bug in the optimizer.

Comment: @LeviRamsey the byte-code, at least `javac` _will_ be emitted. It is known of how little optimizations `javac` does. I doubt `scalac` is any different in this regard.

Comment: @LeviRamsey the JVM does not require the methods to be final to inline them. In fact, the HotSpot JVM will inline so aggressively, that marking a method final has practically no effect in this regard. That’s why `javac` does not spent any effort on it.

Answer (score 0):

It can perform an optimization, yes.

As a matter of fact, it can issue a *single* write, or a single call to `updateMain`. All those three calls will be collapsed to one, only.

But for that to happen, JIT has to prove that nothing else breaks, or more specifically that code does not break the `JMM` rules. In this specific case, as far as I understand it, it does not.

Answer (score -1):

Given the choice is between JVM code that implements

```
   move new value to variable
```

and

```
   compare new value with current value of variable
   if not the same
       move new value to variable
```

the JVM would have to be fairly nutty to implement it the latter way.  That's a pessimization, not an optimization.

The JVM to a large extent relies on the real machine to do simple operations, and real machines store values in memory when you tell them to store values in memory.

Comment: Inserting a such a conditional would not improve the performance, indeed, but it’s not necessary anyway. For a sequence of writes to the same variable, it doesn’t matter whether they write the same value, all but the last one can be omitted.